# $_FILES data not directly available

Tags: php, file, file-upload

When I echo $_FILES['file']['name'] it gives it returns nothing
When I echo $_FILES['file']['name'][0] it returns the correct data.

How come that in every example they can use $_FILES['file']['name'] directly without the extra index?

Answer (score 2):

How the `$_FILES` array is constructed is based on how your html input tags are named.

Your html input is likely

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
```

while in most examples it is

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

The first solution allows to duplicate this line exactly to receive multiple files simultaneously (in an array):

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
```

The second solution only allows exactly this single one file. If one needs to support multiple fileuploads, one has to create a html tag with a different value for the name attribute:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
```

See [this user comment in the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#89674) for a detailed example and the other comments around for futher information how to reorder this array (if one wishes to do so for whatever reason...)